# Redirect all VPS traffic to another VPS

Tags: ubuntu, vps, redirect, traffic

is there any way to redirect all traffic from one VPS to another one? Example, domain is parked with IP 1.1.1.1 but website, smtp, game server, teamspeak server is hosted on 8.8.8.8.. (Ofcourse I could change domain to 8.8.8.8 but I dont want to do it). 
So, I would like to create a chain:
domain -> 1.1.1.1 -> 8.8.8.8

VPS servers are with Ubuntu OS..

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. That's why you should have different MX and A records for all the services you host, so that you have more control over it.

You can make

- www and @ to be 1.1.1.1 to that example.com and www.example.com go where you want.
- mail.domain.com with IP 9.8.7.6 for smtp and imap etc
- an MX record 'mail' (which means it will resolve to mail.domain.com)
- teamspeak.domain.com with ip 2.3.4.5
- unreal.domain.com with IP 1.2.3.4

That's why we have DNS.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a little old question, but I think it may be possible.

You can install a VPN server on your 1.1.1.1 machine and redirects the traffic from certain ports to some VPN clients (you can have a machine on 8.8.8.8, but maybe another on 2.2.2.2, and so on).